# Unable to check the Internet Available

Tags: java, android, android-studio, url, android-webview

I am working on an android application that have a web-view. The problem comes when I want to check whether Internet is available before displaying default message. 
I have studied these links [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038301/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-android-webview-and-show-no-internet-image-n)and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294907/check-whether-connected-to-the-internet-or-not-before-loading-webview). I am confused how to do this.
Here is my code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Web= findViewById(R.id.webview);
    Web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Web.loadUrl("http://yourconsenthomebuilders.com/app/clients");
}
```

Comment: confused means? Have you tried and faced any error? then post that error

Comment: And... what happens? Does it show thepage? Any problems? Any questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this method to check internet connection

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

    public ConnectionDetector() {
    }

    public Boolean check_internet(Context context) {
        if (context != null) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**After this you can create object and check internet connection like this**

Fragment

```
ConnectionDetector connectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector();
connectionDetector.check_internet(getContext())
```

Activity

```
ConnectionDetector connectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector();
connectionDetector.check_internet(this)
```

Comment: where to put this code in the above I have written

Comment: After setContentView called just check this in if(connectionDetector.check_internet(this))

Answer (score 1):

After setContentView()
add this logic

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info != null && info.isAvailable() && info.isConnected())
    {
        //network connected
        //show web view logic here
    }else{
        //network not connected
        //show alerts to users
    }
```

Comment: where to put this code in the above i have writtten

Comment: after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);